# how to skip all the first spaces in a string using shortcuts in C

Tags: c

I wanna to skip all kind of spaces in my string.
I know how to do it the "traditional" way.
I'm not totally familiar with the shortcuts, so I'd like to know why this isn't working:

```
(*str < 33) ? *str++ : 0;
```

gcc tells me that *str++ is unused which I don't get since I'm moving to the next char if the <33 condition is satisfied.

Obviously, I misinterpreted something, could someone tell me what THANKS :O)

Comment: In case of "*str>=33", when do you expect str to be incremented?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Then edit your question to include that, as well as input and the expected and actual output (if you get that far) or the complete and full and unmodified error output from the build.

Comment: Why are you using a ternary instead of an if?

Comment: And if that expression is all you have, then that's not really the way to remove leading spaces from a string. Are you even sure that it's *needed*?

Comment: By the way, I recommend you take some time to read about [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace).

Comment: Maybe `while (isspace((unsigned char) *str)) str++;`?

Comment: The condition `(*str < 33)` will include the terminating null character.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` construct is used to evaluate an *expression*; unless you have this inside of a larger statement, the value of this expression is what is "unused".

As has been commented, if you are trying to decide whether or not to increment `str`, you should be using an `if` statement.